# is it possible to disable the function to hide marker view when touching a value that already shows the marker view in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In default of MPAndroidChart, if I set marker view and touch an value in chart, I can see a marker view about the value. And if I touch it again, the marker view disappears, as far as I know.

At this point, I don't want the marker view to dissapear. Is there any method() or way to prevent marker view hiding?

I have currently made my chart to display multiple marker views with MPAndroidChart.

```
private ArrayList<Highlight> highlightList;

...

public ChartFragment() {
    ...
    highlightList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initializeChart();

            ...

            ChartMarkerView chartMarkerView = new ChartMarkerView(context, R.layout.marker_chart);
            binding.chart.setMarker(chartMarkerView);
            binding.chart.setDrawMarkers(true);
            binding.chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
                    boolean isEqual = false;

                    int size = highlightList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        Highlight highlight = highlightList.get(i);
                        if (highlight.getX() == h.getX() && highlight.getY() == h.getY()) {
                            isEqual = true;

                            highlightList.remove(i);
                            size--;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isEqual) {
                        highlightList.add(h);
                        size++;

                        if (size > activity.settings.getMaxCountOfMarker()) {
                            highlightList.remove(0);
                            size--;
                        }
                    }

                    Highlight[] highlights = new Highlight[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        highlights[i] = highlightList.get(i);
                    }

                    binding.chart.highlightValues(highlights);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected() {

                }
            });

            ...

    }).start();
}
```

When multiple marker views are displayed, accidentally touching a value that is already in a marker view causes all marker views to disappear. It's quite annoying.

Comment: So once the marker view is shown, you want it to stay there permanently? Or you just want touching an existing one to clear only that one, not all of them?

Comment: @TylerV My final goal is "touching an existing one to clear only that one, not all of them". But, the answer about "once the marker view is shown, you want it to stay there permanently" is also helpful. If I get it, it seems to be possible to achieve the final goal.